# How to update specific state in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write quite a simple toDoList with React but stuck with state update. Any help will be appreciated

I have a state array of objects

```
const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([]);

  [
      {
      categoryName: "Free time",
      color: "red",
      id: "30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7",
      tasks: []
      }   
  ]
```

I need to add objects to toDoList.tasks. Objects like this:

```
{
  task: "Watch TV",
  id: "30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7",
  isDone: false,
}
```

How can I update tasks state in toDoList.object?

Answer (score 1):

You can write `addTask` function like this:

```
const addTasks = (task) => {
  const updatedTodoList = toDoList.map((todo) => {
     if(todo.id === task.id){
      todo.tasks.push(task);
     }
     return todo;
  })
  setToDoList(updatedTodoList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `setToDoList` ,you can iterate the data array and check for same id. If it matches then update the task

```js
const data = [{
    categoryName: 'Free time',
    color: 'red',
    id: '30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7',
    tasks: []
  },
  {
    categoryName: 'xxxx',
    color: 'red',
    id: '44444',
    tasks: []
  }
];

const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState(data);

const obj = {
  task: 'Watch TV',
  id: '30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7',
  isDone: false
};

function onclick() {
  setToDoList(elemData => {
    const id = obj.id;
    elemData.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        item.tasks.push(obj);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the initial state of toDoList, your code should read

```
const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([
  {
    categoryName: 'Free time',
    color: 'red',
    id: '30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7',
    tasks: [],
  },
]);
```

If you want to add a subsequent item, use the setToDoList function that the useState hook provides you:

```
setToDoList((previousState) => [
  ...previousState,
  {
    categoryName: 'Free time',
    color: 'red',
    id: '30728c8-13a0-01c1-6385-5307f873d3f7',
    tasks: [],
  },
]);
```

Comment: How can I add object inside tasks array on setToDoList(prevState=>...)

Comment: Exactly how I described it above, although it may be hard to read if you're new to JavaScript. What I'm doing here by calling setToDoList() is saying "Hey React, set the new todo list state to an array that equals the combination of whatever it was before plus this new object." I do this using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)